# Does returning a variable in a function from a different file return reference

Tags: javascript, node.js, reference, copy

If file 2 calls a function in file 1 that returns the reference to a global variable in file 1, does file 2 get a copy or the reference?

file 1:

```
var file2 = require(file2)

getRecord: function() {    
    var record = file2.getObj()
}
```

file 2:

```
module.exports = {
    getObj: function() {
        return obj;
}

var obj = {name: 'bob', value: '4'}
```

Mainly what I'm wondering is if file1 now modifies the 'record' variable, will 'obj' be altered in file2?

It seems like that's what happening in my code, but from what I've read about javascript I would have thought this would send a copy and that altering in file1 would not alter the variable in file2.

Comment: If you are passing an object you are assigning it by reference. If you make changes to your object, it will change on any location. So to your question, if it is an object then yes.